# Помогите распарсить логи

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

Всем привет. Помогите из строки вытащить значения IP для src и dst, а также значение product. Понимаю ,что надо использовать sed и awk. Но мозгов не хватает пока. А нужно , как обычно, вчера. Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Пример строки логов:

```
[action:\"Drop\"; flags:\"133380\"; ifdir:\"inbound\"; ifname:\"WAN\"; loguid:\"{0x620ec1bc,0x0,0x19c8a8c0,0x4258846}\"; origin:\"192.168.1.29\"; time:\"1645134199\"; version:\"1\"; __policy_id_tag:\"product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1[db_tag={053EAC57-90B4-5049-8C1F-6CD550BAEEA0};mgmt=gw-1a6750;date=1643612406;policy_name=Standard\\]\"; dst:\"239.255.255.250\"; inzone:\"External\"; origin_sic_name:\"CN=GW-Test,O=gw-1a6750..obcfwk\"; product:\"VPN-1 & FireWall-1\"; proto:\"2\"; rule:\"6\"; rule_name:\"Cleanup rule\"; rule_uid:\"{53FCFDBF-9053-45C6-93AE-C8AB4C442798}\"; src:\"192.168.1.30\"]
```

Comment: JSON? Так и парсите его по-человечески, с помощью Python и json-парсера.

Comment: Поддержу @0andriy, посмотри в сторону https://github.com/stedolan/jq

Comment: Спасибо всем за помощь. Переделал отправку логов с железки в формат JSON и распарсил с помощь jq.

Answer (score 0):

Я сам *awk* и *sed* забыл давным давно. И мне кажется. что проще всего - на питоне это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений. Вот такая модельная программулька:

```
import re

line = '''[action:\"Drop\"; flags:\"133380\"; ifdir:\"inbound\"; ifname:\"WAN\"; loguid:\"{0x620ec1bc,0x0,0x19c8a8c0,0x4258846}\"; origin:\"192.168.1.29\"; time:\"1645134199\"; version:\"1\"; __policy_id_tag:\"product=VPN-1 & FireWall-1[db_tag={053EAC57-90B4-5049-8C1F-6CD550BAEEA0};mgmt=gw-1a6750;date=1643612406;policy_name=Standard\\]\"; dst:\"239.255.255.250\"; inzone:\"External\"; origin_sic_name:\"CN=GW-Test,O=gw-1a6750..obcfwk\"; product:\"VPN-1 & FireWall-1\"; proto:\"2\"; rule:\"6\"; rule_name:\"Cleanup rule\"; rule_uid:\"{53FCFDBF-9053-45C6-93AE-C8AB4C442798}\"; src:\"192.168.1.30\"]'''

re_src = r'src.+\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}'
result = re.findall(re_src, line)
print(result)
```

Ищет *src* в строке и выдаёт такой результат:

```
['src:"192.168.1.30']
```

Дальнейшее, я думаю, понятно...